# Cookies are hashed or encrypted in the browser?

Tags: cookies, encryption, hash

I run my application Using chrome, then I clicked right click on an empty space on the browser and select "Inspect element" and I found that the cookies is not plain text. Now, I would like to know if it is encrypted or hashed and why??

Also, I want to know if the file (contains cookies) that store on the hard disk are stored as encrypted or as plain text??

In this screen shot, you will see what I am talking about:
[image: Inspect Element]

I wrote (hashed), but not sure if it is encrypted or hashed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JSESSIONID` as used by some Java frameworks is just an ID. It identifies you server sessions. The data is stored on the appserver and *not* in the cookie.

Therefor, the `value` is basically just a `GUID` and (usually) bears no encrypted information.

Comment: So, why the value is not plain text??

Comment: There is no textual representation. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Comment: It was helpful answer, thank you, appreciate your help.